# Desktop Icon Problems with Rotated Unity

Tags: compiz, plugins

I have an odd problem that I'm attributing to the Rotated Unity Plugin.

I can't move any desktop icons any further than where it lies on the left in the following screenshot:

[image]

That "barrier" is where the old launcher used to be. However, observe the next screenshot:

[image]

Here, you can see that the icon can go down into the launcher. I think that the old settings for the normal launcher are implicated though the plugin moved the launcher itself. Any ideas? I'm still a Linux Novice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The launcher still moves to become visible when set to auto-hide, and you are supposed to be able to drop things onto it. At the very least, you should be able to drop things from your desktop and into the waste bucket, which would be impossible if the launcher weren't displayed when you drag something to it.

However, when you move the launcher, the area used to reveal the launcher must also be changed. This appears not to be the case in the software you're using. So this is a bug in the «Rotated Unity Plugin» and you must file a bug against their bug tracker.

Comment: I don't think my question is being understood. I'm not so much worried about the autohide, I'm more concerned about how there is a spot where the launcher used to be that I can't move anything onto

Comment: Right. I understood it. That is where the panel is supposed to be. That's why you can't move things there. There's no panel there to drop things to. The developer of the software you're using, should've taken that into account before releasing the software. You have to find their bug tracker and file a bug against it.

Comment: I'm more or less trying to use that blank space to put desktop icons and shortcuts, not try to drop them on a panel.

Comment: Yes, I understand. There's supposed to be a panel there. You'll have to ask the fork maintainer to fix it. In Unity, it's supposed to be that way. When you move the panel, that area should also be moved to the bottom. He hasn't done so.

Comment: I'll go ahead and contact the developer...if he still is on the project. Thank you!